# ¿Qué sentencia utilizar para capturar el último registro ingresado de 2 tablas a la vez?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Bueno lo que yo deseo hacer es obtener los últimos registros de 2 tablas pero hacerlo en una sola consulta... lo he hecho de esta manera pero no me funciona.

```
SELECT cantidad_bodega,cantidad_camiones 
FROM bodega,camion 
ORDER BY id_bodega and id_camion desc 
LIMIT 1;
```

Cuando lo hago tabla por tabla si funciona pero quiero sacar en una sola sentencia.

Comment: esas tablas están relacionadas de alguna manera?

Comment: No, las tablas son independientes, olvide mencionar eso....

Comment: La razon es porque necesito obtener esos valores para pasarlos a un webservice en android... los 2 juntos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que, como dices en comentario no hay relación entre las tablas, puedes hacer tu consulta así simplemente:

```
SELECT
    a.max_a, 
    b.max_b
FROM 
(SELECT MAX(id_bodega) max_a FROM bodega ORDER BY id_bodega DESC LIMIT 1) a,
(SELECT MAX(id_camion) max_b FROM camion ORDER BY id_camion DESC LIMIT 1) b ;
```

Esta consulta te dará un resultado con una fila y dos columnas:

- `max_a` tendrá el `id_bodega` mayor
- `max_b` tendrá el `id_camion` mayor

Algo así más o menos:

```
max_a            max_b
923822           4
```

---

Si en vez de una fila con dos columnas quieres dos filas con una columna, puedes usar `UNION`:

```
(SELECT MAX(id_bodega) max FROM bodega ORDER BY id_bodega DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT MAX(id_camion) max FROM camion ORDER BY id_camion DESC LIMIT 1);
```

El resultado en este caso sería:

```
max
923822
4
```

Comment: Vaya muchas gracias amigo, me funciono a la perfeccion.... gracias...

Comment: @WilsonCajisaca, me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.